# How to fix a 3D plot with missing values in plot3d

Tags: r, warnings

I'm trying to create a 3d graph with three quantitiave variables (`ama$p_022`, `ama$p_023`, `ama$p_024`) and one categorical (`ama$p`). Quantitatives have `NA`'s and the categorical only two values, but when I use this command

```
plot3d(ama$p_022,ama$p_023,ama$p_024,col=as.integer(ama$p))
```

R gives me a `warning` message

> In f(...) : NAs introduced by coercion

and it doesn't produce the graph. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I changed strings for numbers...